# Почему не подключаются файлы в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

У меня есть файл `.htaccess` в корне сайта:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

и в папке `/web` есть тоже файл `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Пробовал создать ЧПУ, и получилось, только теперь не подключаются стили, JS файлы.
Сервер: OpenServer
В `config/web.php` добавил:

```
'baseUrl' => ''
```

и ещё

```
    'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'suffix' => '.html',
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'pattern' => '',
                    'route' => 'site/index',
                    'suffix' => ''
                ],
                '<action:(about|contact|login)>' => 'site/<action>',
                '<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                'site/hello/<name:\w+>' => 'site/hello',
            ],
        ],
```

Кто-то знает решение?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сделать директорию `web` корнем сайта?

Comment: Да, это я и пробовал сделать.

Comment: Если /web является корнем сайта, то не нужен первый приведенный .htaccess. См ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805855. Проверь лог ошибок веб-сервера, там должно быть написано к каким ресурсам идет запрос и почему он не выполняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в настройках сервера
**Поставил Apache-2.4**
А было Apache-2.4-Nginx-1.7

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/137945)

Comment: @Harry Это же ответ на собственный вопрос.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Это - не конкретный ответ о том, в чем именно проблема - в каких настройках. Если это ответ, то, получается, решение вопроса - в установке другой версии, а эта не будет работать принципиально? тогда надо бы разобрать этот вариант. Возможно, я неправ в выборе именно того, что надо редактирование - выбор, увы, предлагается не охватывающий все варианты, но остаюсь при мнении, что это - "проблема в настройках" - далеко не полный ответ. Который хуже, чем, скажем, ссылка на ответ - там хоть прочесть можно, а тут - догадайся сам. И так понятно, что проблема в настройках. Но в каких?

Comment: @Harry Дело в том, что это *ответ*, а не *"дополнение к вопросу"*. Даже если ответ будет некачественным (спам, бессмысленный бред и прочие очевидные случаи не рассматриваем), то его нельзя удалять через очередь проверок (я не про этот ответ, а вообще). Просто в случае его бесполезности, можно голосовать "против".

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Хорошо, я учту ваше замечание в следующий раз.